# How to use auto filter for multiple data frame in a single sheet using xlswritter

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I am using xlswriter to write dataframe to excel sheet. I am having two dataframe on a same sheet and I want to apply auto filter for both the dataframe.

If I apply the below rule, it applies to only to F1:Q1. Is there any way we can add autofilter to both the dataframe

```
worksheet.autofilter('A1:D1')
 worksheet.autofilter('F1:Q1')
```

I tried the below but removes all the conditional formatting and dataframe column

```
worksheet1.add_table('A1:D4')
worksheet1.add_table('F1:Q15')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have more than one worksheet autofilter in Excel.

However, you can add the dataframes as tables, which will each have an autofilter. Here is an example for one dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country':    ['China',    'India',    'United States', 'Indonesia'],
    'Population': [1404338840, 1366938189, 330267887,       269603400],
    'Rank':       [1,          2,          3,               4]})

# Order the columns if necessary.
df = df[['Rank', 'Country', 'Population']]

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_table.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write the dataframe data to XlsxWriter. Turn off the default header and
# index and skip one row to allow us to insert a user defined header.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Get the dimensions of the dataframe.
(max_row, max_col) = df.shape

# Create a list of column headers, to use in add_table().
column_settings = []
for header in df.columns:
    column_settings.append({'header': header})

# Add the Excel table strucure. Pandas will add the data.
worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {'columns': column_settings})

# Make the columns wider for clarity.
worksheet.set_column(0, max_col - 1, 12)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]

See also [Working with Tables](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_tables.html) in the XlsxWriter docs.